# How to call a function before dropup pops up in Bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my html:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        Hi!
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>LI 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As per documentation, I tried:

```
$("div.dropup").on("show", function(e) {
    alert("hey");
});
```

Is that the correct way to do it? The function is not called though.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are several ways of doing it. In your case you could try

```
$(".dropup").on("show", function(e) {
    alert("hey");
});
```

Also, try to bind the event in `$(document).ready(function(){})` block

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work in my case.

Comment: Idea is bind the event on an object when the object is available. How are you ensuring show and hide?

Comment: Yes, the object is available. I click the button to show/hide the dropup menu.